# SHA1 or MD5 for web applications

Tags: md5, sha1

A lot of people have recently started using SHA1 over MD5. I know that MD5 has it's security flaws but what other reasons is making SHA1 becoming more popular lately?

Comment: Is there a need for other reasons?

Comment: I'm far from an expert but doesn't using a salt get rid of the flaws?

Comment: @Ben: I think that could mitigate them, but you can never have enough security, and switching to a better hash algorithm is a pretty simple change.

Comment: @Ben: I don't believe salt helps at all when it comes to MD5's collision vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Martinho: the main problem is it's not just a matter of switching algorithms; you also have to rehash the original data, which can be tricky when you don't have access to it. Handling users' passwords aren't too bad, as you can mark which users' passwords use which hashing algorithms and force users to enter new passwords to switch them over. I'm not sure if that qualifies as "pretty simple".

Answer (score 5):

SHA1 is also [looking weak](http://www.debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/48) now. For new applications you might as well start with SHA-256.

Answer (score 0):

Lower chance of collisions mostly. It's better in almost every way except backwards compatibility.